# LinqDataSource: How to assign values to where parameters in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linqdatasource

I have the following WhereParameters for LinqDataSource1 in my .aspx file:

```
<WhereParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="key1" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="key2" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
```

How do I assign values to these parameters in my code behind? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign them in the code behind like this:

```
LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Key1"].DefaultValue = "1";
LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Key2"].DefaultValue = "2";
```

Hope this helps.